# Handsontable json update through PHP

Tags: php, json, ajax, handsontable

I am trying to update a json file through a php call.
In my console the parameter is not empty but when I retrieve the json file the value are not there.

the save function is the following:

```
Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(save, 'click', function() {
  var dataarray = JSON.stringify(hot.getData());
  ajax ('json/projectupdate.php', 'POST', {"infos:":dataarray}, function (res) {
    console.log (dataarray)
  });
```

in the console the result is the following:

```
[["test1","","gep2","",null,null,null,null,null],["","test1","","gep2",null,null,null,null,null],["dag","","test1","","gep2",null,null,null,null],["","dag","","test1",null,"gep2",null,null,null],["","","dag","","test1",null,"gep2",null,null],["","","","dag",null,"test1",null,"gep2",null],[null,null,null,null,"dag",null,"test1",null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,"dag",null,"test1",null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,"dag",null,"test1"],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,"dag",null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]
```

that is actual what I wrote in the table.
Then I pass (or at least I try to pass) my var to my (`projectupdate.php`) php file:

```
<?php 
  $myFile = "project.json"; 
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
  $stringData = $_POST['infos']; 
  $stringData1='{ "data":'$stringData'}'; 
  fwrite($fh, $stringData1); 
  fclose($fh); 
?>
```

the result is that `projectupdate.php` write on `project.json` `"{ "data":}"` but nothing else.
I am doing something wrong for sure.

Comment: `$stringData1='{ "data":'$stringData'}'` looks like it should be `$stringData1='{ "data":' . $stringData . '}'`.

Comment: mmm... I tried but the result is the same....

Comment: Try echoing it on server `var_dump($_POST['infos']);`;